# variable initialization using class member function

Tags: c++

Why the head is not NULL at the beginning if I initialized it with the class member function? It is a tricky part.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};


class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head;
public:

    void push(node *head, int data);
    void printList(node *head);
    void printMiddle(node *head);
    void makeHeadNull(node *head);
};

void linked_list::push(node *head, int data)
{
    node *newNode=new node;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
}



void linked_list::printMiddle(node *head)
{

        node *slow_ptr = head;
        node *fast_ptr = head;

        if (head!=NULL)
        {
            while (fast_ptr != NULL && fast_ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                fast_ptr = fast_ptr->next->next;
                slow_ptr = slow_ptr->next;
            }
            cout<<slow_ptr->data<<" ";
    }



void linked_list::printList(node *head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;

    }
}

void linked_list::makeHeadNull(node *head)
{
    head=NULL;
}



int main()
{
    node *head;
    linked_list l;
    l.makeHeadNull(head);


    l.push(head, 0);
    l.push(head, 1);
    l.push(head, 2);
    l.push(head, 3);
    l.push(head, 4);

    l.printMiddle(head);
}
```

I wanted to initialize head inside a constructor, but when I initialized head like that, the head node has always been NULL inside main. When I initialize head in the constructor and then I want to pass it as a parameter of a function push I get errors.

Comment: Would you mind to narrow down your code example to the parts relevant for your question please. See how to create [MCVE].

Comment: ok, now I will post the minimized version

Comment: Where is this constructor of which you speak?

Comment: BTW: The list should not expose the `node` type. You seem to be trying to force a non-object-oriented list into objects.

Comment: I deleted the constructor to minimize the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the head is not NULL at the beginning if I initialized it with the class member function.

You never use that member variable. Instead you pass `head` that is local variable in `main` and you've left that variable uninitialized.

Note that your `push` neither modifies the member `head` nor does it modify the local variable in `main`. `head = newNode;` modifies the variable that is local to the member function which is destroyed when the function returns making the assignment pointless.

I suspect that your intention was to modify either the member, or the pointer passed to the function. To modify the passed pointer, pass a reference to it. To modify the member variable, use `this->` or don't hide the member with a local variable with the same name.

Comment: @Tat well, what do you intend to do with the `head` argument of the `push` function? What is the relationship between that argument and the member variable `head`?

Comment: I thought it would push the class member variable head, but after your post I understood that it is not the class member variable head, it is the function's own head

Comment: I solved the problem where can I post the solution for people who will be interested